# How to remove "Done" button from AlertDialog in Android L?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android L Dev Preview TimePickerDialog contains an additional button "Done", which is the same as "Positive button". Is this a default behaviour of pickers in Android Lolipop or it's just a preview bug? 
Is there a way to remove it?
Here is code which creates dialog:

```
DialogFragment timePickerFragment = new DialogFragment()
      {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
          TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
          {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hours, int minutes)
            {
              DoStuff(hours * TimeUtils.HOUR_MINUTES + minutes);
            }
          };
          TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, listener, 0, 0, true);
          dialog.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", dialog);
          dialog.setButton(TimePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", dialog);
          dialog.setTitle("Set time");
          return dialog;
        }
      };

      timePickerFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time_picker");
```

Result in KitKat (as expected):
[image: Result in KitKat (as expected)]

Result in Lolipop (with "Done" button)
[image: Result in Lolipop (with "Done" button)]

Comment: Try :  ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(whichButton).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @HareshChhelana there is no constant for "done" button

Comment: Yes dear you are right i also not finding any constant for Done button in TimePickerDialog.

Comment: ,from kitkat by default Done button came in time picker so in your case not use setButton() for ok and cancel.

Comment: What version of L Preview are you using? The "done" button shouldn't be appearing in the most recent preview build.